# How to move an image on mouse over with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, menu

My code doesn't work.
 Currently the mouse over part is working but not mouse out .

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeBtn(x){
       x.style.marginTop="50px";
  }
    function returnBtn(y){
       y.style.marginTop="-50px";
  }
```

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="home.html" target="some_page"><img src="images/home.gif" alt="home"     onmouseover="changeBtn(this)" onmouseout="returnBtn(this)"></a></li>

</ul>
```

Firebug shows an error on line 6 :"marginTop is ignored"

Comment: This site is called "stackoverflow" not "wedoyourhomework".

Comment: What have you tried? Remember CSS is for presentation aspects so I guess that is what you need to know to not use CSS to solve the assignment.

Comment: Are you saying your lecturer never covered any of this in class?

Comment: Please do not ask *"How to create $entire_system_xyz?"* type questions here. Try to build $entire_system_xyz yourself and ask concrete questions about problems you encounter, complete with code samples. There are thousands of ways to do what you ask and StackOverflow is not for providing solutions to problems as broad as this.

Comment: Try table , with the help of td, tr u can manage it . and for java script part on click of td show same index td of other row will look like menu :)

Comment: If you can't use tags then all you have is a single line of meaningless  text. You are probably going to need to use document.write to output your menu.

Comment: If you can use HTML, but not CSS, then look up how to do it using CSS and add those styles to your elements using JavaScript. I should mention that this seems like an awfully stupid assignment. It teaches you bad practices.

Comment: @Trendy : Thank you. I used java script as you have mentioned. My code: ` <img src="images/home.gif" alt="home" onmouseover="changeBtn(this)" onmouseout="returnBtn(this)"> ` mouseover is working,but not mouseout.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen : ok,i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: nvm, i got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
<a href="home.html" target="content"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('homeImg').src='images/frnds-btn.gif';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('homeImg').src='images/hobbies-btn.gif';" ><img src="images/home-btn.gif"  alt="home" id="homeImg" ></a>
```

i used other images to test the current code.